# How can I include text message in an intent chooser's list?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, mms

I have the following code:

```
cookieBitmap.compress(
                        Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 
                        100, 
                        new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/cookie.jpg")));
                Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                picMessageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                File fortuneFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/cookie.jpg");
                picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fortuneFile));
                Log.i("INFO","At BEFORE INTENT");
                if (prepareTask.isCancelled()) {return false;}
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, getString(R.string.sendcookieusing)));
```

On my galaxy vibrant, the chooser includes android's text messaging app. When I pick this, it starts the operating system's new text activity and places the image in the text as an attached picture. However, I've ran my app on a myTouch 3G and a myTouch 3G Slide and the text messaging option does not show up. How can I make it so that to text message the picture is an option on those phones?

Has anyone experienced this problem? How many types of phones will have this problem? My app is currently on the market but no one has downloaded it. How much concern should I have? If it only affects myTouch phones I think I can put it off fixing this for a couple of days.

Thanks

EDIT: I think this happens on phones with HTC sense rom.